# Blocks won't break without right tool

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm not in Adventure Mode, but I must use the right tools to destroy blocks. It does it at some points while I am playing, and then it stays like that and don't know why. Does anyone know what i am on about?

Comment: **How to write a proper question:** 1: Add some punctuation so people can understand the text. 2: Make sure you write the question in such way that people can provide an answer. 3: Add details to the question that you think are important.

Comment: Some helpful details you should provide: What blocks? What tools? Do you have any mods installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try check this thread out: [Blocks won't break unless with right tools?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118989/blocks-wont-break-unless-with-right-tools)

Are you sure you are not in adventure mode? If it happens in single-player, then try to make another world and see if it's just that one save. If it's on a multiplayer server, then try another to test, if it's the same.